# How to use python "Fire" library when using with a Com-Port?

Tags: python

I do have a class which opens and a class which sets a gpio of that comport.

```
import sys
import serial
import fire


from serial import Serial


class Russ_GPIO(object):
    def __init__(self, port="COM4")
        self.com4 = serial.Serial("COM4", baud, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False, timeout=timeout, parity=parity)
        time.sleep(0.5)

        self.com4.rts = False


    
    def set_gpio(self, state ):     
        if state == 0: 
            self.com4.rts = False                       
        else:
            self.com4.rts = True  
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(Russ_GPIO)
```

Now when use the command line with:

```
python ComPort.py set_gpio 0
```

Then I see that the com_port is opening but will close right after again. How can I use the command line command in order that the com-port remains open? Is this possible?

In other words, how can I avoid that the class is not destroyed after a sent the command line cmd??

Comment: What do you want to achieve by keeping the com-port open?

Comment: That the control line does not fall back to its default state

Comment: No. By definition, file handles are closed when the process ends.  That's just how it works.  However, RTS should not change just because you close the file.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok, understood. But when I run my code the RTS remains allways in the same state and I can not change it. Is my code correct?

Comment: Well, the code you have above will not run, because `state` is not defined in `if state == 0:`.  Your `serial.Serial` line should use `port` instead of hardcoding `"COM4"`, but that's not relevant here.  Also make sure you're not confusing "active low" and "active high".  In some designs, setting RTS `false` sets it to logic high.

Comment: you are right about the "state" but also when I have changed it, I can not set RTS to high or low value with "set_gpio".

Comment: It works as long I use the python shell and the class is still valid. After you close the shell the RTS line goes to its default state back.